# Google Apps Script : not reliable time triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

is it allowed to chain time triggers in Google App script like this :

```
 function doGet(e){   //first invocation by user, HTTP GET 
    if (e == null || e.parameters == null) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("EMPTY");
    }

    saveGetParametersForUser(Session.getUser().getEmail(), e);

    //trigger 10 seconds
    var timeTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("timeDrivenEvent").timeBased().after(10 * 1000).create();

 }


function timeDrivenEvent() { //runs until there are some data in ScriptDB
  Logger.log("INVOKED AT " + new Date());

  removeAllPreviousTriggers(); //removes old time triggers

  var somedata = loadTaskData({email: "" + Session.getUser().getEmail()});
  var remainingData = processTaskData(somedata);

    if(remainingData == null){
       return; //we are finished here
    } 

  removePreviousAndSaveRemainingTaskData(remainingData);

  var timeTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("timeDrivenEvent").timeBased().after(10 * 1000).create();

}
```

- First invocation by user doGet()
- Until all data are processed script invokes itself with 10 sec intervals (e.g. 2minutes of processing, 10 seconds nothing happens, then again 2 minutes of processing...)
- size of processed data is ~ few kilobytes and processing time takes usually 1-2mins.

What happens to me that **sometimes** script is interrupted and data are not fully processed ! I am not getting any email alerts and nothing is in log or execution transcript - everything looks fine.

I am starting to think that maybe 10 seconds is quite quick to start script method but it`s in the API after all...

Any ideas ?
This is ONLY POSSIBLE solution how to chunk big task into smaller pieces as Google App Script cannot run for more than ~ 5-6 minutes (see quotas).

Comment: How much total processing time would you use per day?

Comment: During development i am running script at least 20x per day... That does not go over 1 hour / day which is limit for free google apps. We do have google apps for business (bigger quotas).

Comment: I fear that you're hitting the 20 Trigger quota per script. Your code that you've given is repeatedly creating triggers. So maybe you should  delete previous triggers? That'd be `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()`. Check if the handler function is `"timeDrivenEvent"`, then delete it if it is using `ScriptApp.deleteTrigger()`.

Comment: Why don't you use one single trigger that fires every 5 minutes and gets deleted when task is completed ?

Comment: @Phil Bozak : Nope, i do have something like method deleteAllTrigersForScript() in my script where i am removing all trigers... (i did not mentioned that due siplifications). I am checking active triggers in my script and usually have 1-2 active triggers there. @Serge : It`s worth to try but user experience will be a bit worse, as i will start after some defined time and not immediately...

Comment: not necessarily, you can call the function directly on the first call without using the trigger, the second (and following) call would be "timer triggered". let us know what you come to after your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Having one periodic time trigger worked well as it was recommended in comments.

I just wonder why time trigger chaining didnt worked well ! What principle i did broke that Google App Script didnt like that.

Documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clocktriggerbuilder

method everyMinutes Sets the trigger to be created to fire on an interval of the passed in number of minutes which must be one of 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30.

Comment: Thanks for updating, glad to know it helped.

Comment: This new solution brings new problems. I will have to propably use some locking as script can sometimes run twice at the same time (e.g. when processing times is > 1 minute second instance of script start to run as i am using everyMinute(1). Google App Script brings a lot of pain to me.

Comment: You can use a flag stored in ScriptProperties to allow the script to run only if the current chunk is processed- or you could use a 5 minutes trigger to be sure you get no 'overlap'.

Comment: @MartinV. Even better is probably to use `LockService.getPrivateLock();` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service